# php fetch data from the database in an array format

Tags: php, sorting, arraylist, mysqli

I am just a newbie in php. I have a database, in the database the data is like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;


INSERT INTO `list` (`id`, `data`) VALUES
(1, '5,2,3,4,1');
```

Now to fetch the data I have made my php code like this

```
<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $db = 'sortable';

    $link=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno($link)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $query = "SELECT `data` FROM `list`";
    $order = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    print_r($order);
  ?>
```

here its showing the result like this

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )
```

But I want the fetch values will be in array and the desired output of the array will be like this

```
   Array([0] => Array([0]=>5,2,3,4,1[data]=>5,2,3,4,1))
```

So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking up the mysqli_* commands in the php database found [HERE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)? it's pretty useful. try using the mysqli_fetch_array(); or mysqli_fetch_assoc();

an example using your php code could be this:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = 'sortable';

$link=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno($link)) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$query = "SELECT `data` FROM `list` WHERE `id` = '1'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $numbers = $data['data'];
echo $numbers;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this Output

```
Array([0] => Array([0]=>5,2,3,4,1)

**Use this**

<?php

    define('HOST', 'localhost');
    define('USER', 'root');
    define('PASS', '');
    define('DBNAME', 'sortable');

    $db = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DBNAME);

    if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" 
    . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT `data` FROM `list` WHERE `id` = '1'";
    $result_db = $db->query($sql) or die("Error!");
    $all_result = $result_db->fetch_all();
    print_r($all_result);

    $db->close();
    ?>
```